# Webpack Module Federation changes names of shared libraries to numbers

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-5, webpack-module-federation

With Webpack Module Federation, how do I **retain development filenames** when building as production?

Currently, it's changing them all to numbers like `3279.js` instead of something like `src_applications_myApp_jsx.js`.

Parts of the Webpack config:

```js
const { dependencies } = require('../package.json');

output: {
  chunkFilename: 'vendor/[name].js',
  filename: '[name]/app.js',
},

new webpack.container.ModuleFederationPlugin({
  shared: dependencies,
}),
```

The issue is the `chunkFilename`. Changing it to `'vendor/[id].js'` doesn't change anything either.

Webpack's docs say the `[name]` property will only work if the chunk has a name. So I guess, why is a name not set?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for chunks you can just use

```
webpackConfig.optimization.chunkIds='named'
```

It'll keep your chunk names readable, see link for further docu
https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/#optimizationchunkids